# Changing validationsummary-text from resourcefile

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if you guys know howto get the validationsummary "title" from resouce-file?

got this atm:

```
Html.ValidationSummary("Information missing.")
```

For my validation I use stuff like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName="UsernameRequired")]
public object Username { get; set; }
```

How can I fix that?

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood well the nature of the problem, but you could do it like this if you have access to the resource file from web application project:

```
Html.ValidationSummary(Resources.YourInfomrationMissingKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about expression builder syntax?

[ResourceExpressionBuilder Class (System.Web.Compilation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceexpressionbuilder.aspx)

[Basic Instincts: Resources and Localization in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx)